# Is there a way to access the individual authors given by \author?

Tags: beamer, titles, beamerposter

suppose I have several authors that I have declared via the `\author` command in latex-beamer, e.g.

```
\author{Einstein \and Podolsky \and Rosen}
```

I was wondering whether there is a way to access the individual names, i.e. something like

```
authors[0] == "Einstein"
authors[1] == "Podolsky"
authors[2] == "Rosen"
```

I would like to display all names with a corresponding QR-Code for contact information at the bottom of a conference poster. Sure, I could just retype the names again but I guess that is a rather inelegant way.

Comment: Have you tried something like using `authblk`? http://ctan.org/pkg/authblk (Just throwing out an idea, don't know if it would work or not.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `etoolbox` lets you process lists separated by a catcode 3 `|`. If you convert `\and` into `|` then you can process the authors as a list. For classes that do not redefine `\author` the following should work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\author{Einstein \and Podolsky \and Rosen}

\makeatletter
\begingroup
  \catcode`|=3\relax
  \def\and{|}
  \newcounter{@authorCount}
  \def\do#1{
    \stepcounter{@authorCount}
    \csgdef{author\Roman{@authorCount}}{#1}
  }
  \edef\eauthor{\@author}
  \dolistloop{\eauthor}%
\endgroup
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\authorI

\authorII

\authorIII
\end{document}
```

The `beamer` class redefines `\author` so you need to replace `\edef\eauthor{\@author}` with `\edef\eauthor{\beamer@shortauthor}`.